# PHP-FFMpeg prerequisites

Tags: php, oop, ffmpeg

<strike>I'm attempting to implement https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg</strike>

I copied the src/FFMpeg folder to my includes folder and made sure my autoloader knows where to find everything.

as a test I made a script that simply does:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
```

I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found in /var/www/php/include/FFMpeg/FFProbe.php on line 203
```

My question is: does PHP-FFMPeg require Doctrine, because that is not stated in the documentation. What version do I need? Are there other prerequisites?

I could create a new question for this, but I'm not sure if I should. I now have PHP-ffmpeg implemented. I'm using Laravel, however that should be irrelevant for this question. I'm trying to enable progress monitoring. It works, however I need to pass in an ID so I can update the correct key in memcache.

```
$id = 12345;
$format->on('progress', function ($audio, $format, $percentage) {
    //this works perfect, but doesn't tell me which item is being updated 
    Cache::put("progress", $percentage,  .25);

    //this does not work as I am unable to pass in $id, if I add it as the 4th argument above it will display the number of threads or something
    //Cache::put("{$id}_progress", $percentage,  .25);          
});
```

I need clarification on the "on" method. I looked through https://ffmpeg-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_static/API/ and was not able to figure out how this method works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the [composer requirements](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/composer.json), it uses the Doctrine Cache component among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the [recommended instructions in the README](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#installation).

Composer is the easiest way to install PHP-FFMpeg dependencies

The "on" method called on the format is an implementation of EventEmitter.
As you can see here : https://ffmpeg-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_static/API/FFMpeg/Format/ProgressableInterface.html it extends the EventEmitterInterface of https://github.com/igorw/evenement.

If you're really interested about how it works under the hood, have a look at here :
The progress listener is created here : https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/src/FFMpeg/Format/Audio/DefaultAudio.php#L96 and added at execution here https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/src/FFMpeg/Media/Video.php#L151
This is actually possible because FFMpegDriver extends the Driver provided by https://github.com/alchemy-fr/BinaryDriver

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, the only reason I didn't use composer is that I am not familiar with it and did not think it was necessary. I'll read up on it.

Comment: I have it working, but I have a question about progress monitoring (I updated the question above)